# Passing along an ASPX hidden field to a webmethod with an AJAX call

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a hidden field called 'hfID' on my ASP page that I am trying to pass along to a Webmethod via an ajax call.  However this generates an Internal Server 500 error.  This is obviously not the entire section but the relevant part.  My suspicion is that I'm not grabbing the hfID value properly at the outset.  The C# method has an 'ID' parameter.

This is the ASP code:

< asp:HiddenField runat="server" id="hfID"/ >

Here is the JavaScript:

```
 app.$tabPanel.on("click", "div.blob-field div.editor .save", function () {
        var $tabContent = $(this).closest("div.blob-field"),
            fieldName = $tabContent.data("fieldName"),
            content = $tabContent.find("div.editor textarea").val(),
            ID = $(this).find("hfID").val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            url: "FileName.aspx/MethodName",
            data: JSON.stringify({
                fieldName: fieldName,
                content: content,
                ID: ID 
            })
```

Comment: ID = $(this).find("<%=hfID.ClientID%>").val();

Comment: And the method signature should have those three fields in that order? Does the type matter?

Comment: The order has to be same order with the MethodName parameters order and it is case sensitive